# Get rid of the "scope" tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

We have both a [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and a [variable-scope](/questions/tagged/variable-scope).  It seems to me one should be a synonym for the other.

---

**edit**

After @al-everett's answer below, I realized the problem might be the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag in general.  I can think of two (maybe three) distinct definitions that fit:  The vast majority of questions tagged [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) seem to regard *variable scope* in a particular language, but some also refer to *project scope* (as in scope creep).

We also use the term at my company to refer to *application scope*--which data is being operated on or displayed (active date range, especially)--but I'm not sure if this is an industry-wide use of the term, or just our local lingo.

Is this tag just too general/ambiguous?

Comment: I have used "data scoping" before to mean the active data range

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag should be black listed as it has no meaning on its own. Then all the questions on the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag should be retagged.

Comment: I agree that it should be blocked.  The questions should use a more specific "scope" tag: [variable-scope], [application-scope], [project-scope], etc.  Though scope does have meaning on it's own I think, it's just that it has different meanings in different contexts and is therefore ambiguous.

Comment: So what's the etiquette with this on meta?  Do I accept this answer, even though I don't have the rep to perform this clean up? (and it's gonna be a lot of clean up).  Should I retag this question as feature-request or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Update: 3 years later, there has been no change.

While I support deletion of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) in general, until that happens (*if* that happens), in any case [variable-scope](/questions/tagged/variable-scope) should a synonym for [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

Current tag descriptions:

> **scope**: Scope is an enclosing context where values and expressions are associated. Use this tag for questions about different types of scope as well for questions where scope may be unclear.
>
> **variable-scope**: A variable scope is the context within a computer program in which a variable name is valid and can be used.

While there are valid differences between the two; it appears that many questions tagged *scope* should have been tagged *variable-scope* instead: The reason is because most people would refer to that as just "scope". I do not feel there is much value in separating the two anyways (in fact, I don't feel like their is much value in either of these tags, in all cases the general language tag is appropriate -- also, "scope" itself seems frequently misused to refer specifically to Ruby on Rails' `scope`).

I think the blurry line between these two tags, the common misuse of one when the other (or something else entirely) was meant, and the relative non-usefulness of these tags in general warrants a merge.

Even better would be a blacklist of both, after manually retagging the Ruby on Rails `scope` questions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the questions, I think variable-scope should be set as the synonym for scope.  However, I don't have enough rep in the tags to make the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

"Scope" is too generic for a synonym, I think. What about Requirements scope?

Comment: That raises an interesting point: the word "scope" has multiple definitions in programming.  I've edited my question to address this as well.

Answer (score -1):

The question is, what is the scope of the scope (lots of flavours to chose from):

- scope× 1039
- variable-scope× 397
- transactionscope× 207
- named-scope× 152
- cscope× 47
- gyroscope× 21
- scope-identity× 20
- default-scope× 14
- lexical-scope× 12
- sessionscope× 9
- scope-creep× 7
- dynamic-scope× 7
- scope-resolution× 6
- scopes× 5
- transaction-scope× 4
- session-scope× 4
- global-scope× 4
- scope-chain× 4
- oscilloscope× 4
- named-scopes× 4
- scopeguard× 4
- flash-scope× 4
- shareddbconnectionscope× 3
- scoped-lock× 3
- scoped-ptr× 3
- anonymous-scope× 2
- scope-id× 2
- inputscope× 2
- sync-scope
- scoped-proxy