# When do you accept an answer on meta?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, meta

A while ago, I posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82094/get-rid-of-the-scope-tag) here on meta.  It got a good answer with a handful of upvotes, which I totally agree with.  However, having an answer and having someone do the footwork of cleaning up the tag in question are two different things.  And I don't have the rep to perform the cleanup myself.

So what's the general rule of etiquette here on meta?  Do I accept the answer I think is right and hope someone notices who can perform the clean up?  Do I retag it somehow to get the attention of someone who can do something about it (though I'm not sure "feature-request" is a fitting tag)?  Or do I do nothing, since it has naturally buried itself, and apparently hasn't garnered enough attention to result in the blacklisting of the tag?

Comment: I accept an answer on meta if I believe a consensus has been established.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You accept an answer when someone posts an answer that is acceptable in answering your question!

Seriously though, accepting isn't as expected here on MSO and certainly less so for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) posts.  There's even an [open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/dont-calculate-accepted-answer-rate-on-meta) to not calculate the accept rate on MSO because it's so different.  Typically I've accepted when either someone has posted an answer that answers my question or when a dev has explained why something is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), etc.  Otherwise, I don't accept.

As far as bumping things politely to get more attention, the same rules apply here as any of the StackExchange sites really.  I've taken long-dormant questions and changed them from [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as well when I thought it was warranted, and I've politely bumped things as well.

Comment: The other meta sites don't show accept rate, so the fact that MSO does means it must be intentional.

Comment: @Gabe Good question; might be because it's a stand-in for "Stack Exchange meta", despite its name and it being paired up with Stack Overflow main. Perhaps someone in charge can give an official answer.