# What is the meaning of accepting an answer (esp. less upvoted) in the child meta sites?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, per-site-meta

In child meta-s, we often try to get community consensus about certain policy or rule by asking a question.

But let's say that, the OP (which can be a Mod also) accepts an answer which satisfies their query. But community members may have upvoted other answers more than the accepted one.
**What does such "acceptance" mean in a meta site?**

<sub>[Note: I could find following post which relates to my query:

[When do you accept an answer on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85095/163449)

The accepted answer suggests that, it's not expected to accept an answer when there is a tag [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)]</sub>

Comment: The majority doesn't determine the consensus but the usefulness of the answer to the situation determines. See [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/357396).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Child metas are odd. It simply means the OP preferred that answer.

While in theory, a lot of the time rules are by community consensus, sometimes certain answers are more correct, match SE rules or simply be better somehow.

If its a moderator, it *may* be a reflection of the current moderation policy, but it really depends on the broader context of the post.

On the other hand, a more popular, and selected answer may end up getting ignored if a mod posts an answer laying out current moderation policy.