# Merge tag [variable-scope] into [scope]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get rid of the “scope” tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82094/get-rid-of-the-scope-tag)

Merge [variable-scope](/questions/tagged/variable-scope) into [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) as a synonym.

Well technically, there could be questions about scope of non-variable identifiers, but that distinction seems pointless.